# Installing LASzip in Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, lidar, ubuntu, laszip

I have tried without any success to install LASzip[¹](http://download.osgeo.org/laszip/) [²](http://www.laszip.org/) ([paper by Isenburg about LASzip](http://www.cs.unc.edu/%7Eisenburg/lastools/download/laszip.pdf)) on Ubuntu 16.04.

The basic way gave me nothing relevant:

```
./configure && make & checkinstall
```

which seems to install some .a, .la, .so.6 and other .hpp files under `/usr/local` but no binaries (which are mandatory to install other "packages" like pdal)

I wonder if these tools were included in [libLAS](http://www.cs.unc.edu/%7Eisenburg/lastools/download/laszip.pdf) but it doesn't seem so: some of them does exist within libLAS and others not.

Comment: Are you looking for lastools? http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/ but read the license for usage limits: http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/LICENSE.txt

Comment: Not a proper answer to your question, but note that SAGA GIS and QGIS, which both run happily on Ubuntu, can handle LAS files and LiDAR processing too.

Comment: As far as I know, the only way for QGIS to load and work on *.LAS files is with LAStools and they need Wine to work (they only exist as *.exe). I do not have the possibility to install Wine on this machine. 

And it's a mess ; there is a LASzip folder within the LAStools github repo and there is also a LASzip github repo... Which one to use ?

Anyway, when compiling PDAL using CMake I alway end up with this message :

-- The following RECOMMENDED packages have not been found:

 * LASzip
   Provides LASzip compression

Comment: @s.k. Clone LASzip from Github and then checkout tag 2.0.2. PDAL does not work with 2.2.0, the latest version.

Answer (score 5):

PDAL requires version 2.0.2 of LASzip.

Version 2.2.0, which, at the time of writing, is what you're getting from any ZIP download for Github clone includes the following [release note](https://github.com/LASzip/LASzip/releases/tag/v2.2.0):

> A number of changes were made to the header files and a new minor release was made instead of a simple point release as a precaution.

Therefore, what you want to do is:

```
git clone https://github.com/LASzip/LASzip.git
git tag #List tags
git checkout tags/2.0.2
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

After this things should work swimmingly, at least for PDAL.

**Edit (2019-03-27):**

It works as well with version 3.3.1 (as of 2019-03-27):

```
cd /opt
git clone https://github.com/LASzip/LASzip.git
mkdir LASzip/build && cd LASzip/build
cmake-gui ..
```

Configure and generate project using `cmake-gui`. Then:

```
make
sudo make install
```